# Ouvir múltiplos eventos no jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe alguma forma simplificada de fazer um seletor ouvir vários tipos de eventos?

Exemplo:

```
$('meu-seletor').on(['click','touchstart','keyup'],function(){
    // minha ação aqui
});
```

Atualmente a única solução que eu conheço seria criar múltiplos `.on()` cada um chamando um único evento. É possível fazer de alguma outra forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é só separar com espaços:

```
$('meu-seletor').on('click touchstart keyup', function(){
    // minha ação aqui
});
```

Na [documentacão do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) diz:

> One or more space-separated event types
>   *Um ou mais tipos de evento separados por espaços*

Comment: Puts, sério isso?! Bem mais simples do que eu imaginava.

Comment: @Kazzkiq Mas cuidado que tem dispositivo que dispara tanto o click quanto o touchstart. Aí seu listener vai rodar dobrado.

Comment: Bem visto @bfavaretto!